# java swing : Polygon fill color problem

Tags: java, swing

Could any body diagnose the problem I am facing?
As you run the demo you can see the middle part left blank, I need to fill the entire area..

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class FillDemo
{
    public static void main(String aths[])
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel pnl = new PolygonDemo();
        pnl.setSize(100, 200);
        f.getContentPane().add(pnl);
        f.setSize(400,280);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true); 
    }
}

class PolygonDemo extends JPanel
{
    public PolygonDemo()
    {
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        Polygon p=new Polygon();

        p.addPoint(100,0);
        p.addPoint(100,100);
        p.addPoint(0,100);
        p.addPoint(0,0);

        p.addPoint(80,0);
        p.addPoint(80,20);
        p.addPoint(40,20);
        p.addPoint(40,40);
        p.addPoint(80,40);
        p.addPoint(80,100);
        p.addPoint(20,100);
        p.addPoint(20,80);
        p.addPoint(60,80);
        p.addPoint(60,60);
        p.addPoint(20,60);
        p.addPoint(20,0);
        p.addPoint(0,0);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(p);
        g2.setColor(new Color(120,250,100));
        g2.fillPolygon(p);
        //g2.fillPolygon(p.xpoints,p.ypoints,p.npoints);

    }

}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your polygon intersects with itself. The fillPolygon method can not clearly decide which point is in and which is out. From the fillPolygon javadoc:

> The area inside the polygon is defined using an even-odd fill rule, also known as the alternating rule.

Perhaps you can split your polygon into three single ones.

Comment: Thanks Nokul for immediate and right reply 
I could able to fill now with the following changes 

g2.fillPolygon(p.xpoints,p.ypoints,4);
         g2.fillPolygon(p);

But now my drawn lines are not visible. I mean can I simply apply a different color to my curves so it could be visible?

Thanks again

Comment: Try calling fillPolygon before calling draw.

Comment: Great!! A big thank you again it's being done. with below changes as per your suggestion:
g2.setColor(new Color(120,250,100));
         g2.fillPolygon(p.xpoints,p.ypoints,4);
         g2.fillPolygon(p);
         g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         g2.draw(p);

Answer (score 2):

Draw Rectangle and Fill Color.....

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
int[] xPoints = {100,50,150};
int[] yPoints = {100,200,200};

      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);

    }
```